# Save to drive vs File Picker

Tags: file-upload, google-drive-api

My main objective is to upload files to drive from my device ( a web application in JS) and read files from Drive. Exploring for the same scenario , i was confused with two API-SaveToWeb and FilePicker , from Google drive , which actually provides the same functionality (upload files to drive ) .

Help me to understand which one is used in which scenario ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In some scenarios you could use either, but it depends a bit on your use case and the UX you want.

The save to drive button is useful when you know the specific file that the user will want to save.  Its a very simple UX where you just put the button next to the specific file(s).

The file picker is used when you want the user to select the file that they will update.  Its a little more involved, but gives the users more control over what they select.

Comment: Are there any other API like File picker for Google drive, which gives the user ,the selection of files to upload in drive.